# How to enable header in text files of load_dataset in huggingface?

Tags: python, nlp, header, huggingface-datasets, huggingface

I am trying to load a text file using huggingface (https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.2.1/loading_datasets.html)

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset('text', data_files='my_file.txt')
```

This text file already contains headers, how do I indicate this to the module (say, `header = True`, in case of pandas `read_csv()`)?

Also, how do I mention that it is tab/comma separated?

Is there a way to present this data in tabular format?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for newcomers:

Read tsv file:

```
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("csv", 'path/to/your/file.tsv', delimiter='\t')
```

By default, it will infer the column names from the first line.

If your file don't have a header line and you want to specify the column names, use

```
column_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
dataset = load_dataset("csv", 'path/to/your/file.tsv', delimiter='\t', column_names=column_names)
```

See the docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.12.0/en/package_reference/loading_methods#datasets.packaged_modules.csv.CsvConfig

Answer (score 0):

They are using [pandas.read_csv()](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.18.2/package_reference/main_classes.html?highlight=csv#datasets.Dataset.from_csv) and you can pass parameters through load_dataset:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset

a = load_dataset("csv", data_files="bla.tsv", sep="\t")
```

Comment: But load_datasets doesn't take 'sep' argument.

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of datasets? The code above works fine with the latest version.

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps 'csv' is working fine with me even without 'sep='. The 'txt' is troublesome.

Comment: Please post the line you are executing. Maybe also post a few lines of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it by `pandas` and then convert to a dataset:

```
  from datasets import Dataset
  import pandas as pd

  df = pd.read_table(path)
  ds = Dataset.from_pandas(df)
```